# equivalence of two measures

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory

Show that, if for two $\sigma$-finite measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ defined on a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathscr{F}$, one has $\mu(A)=\nu(A)$ for all $A\in\mathscr{A}$, where $\sigma(\mathscr{A})=\mathscr{F}$, then $\mu=\nu$. Can some give me hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Assume first that $\mu(X) < \infty$, where $X$ is the entire space. ($X \in \mathcal{A}$)
2. Apply Dynkin's Lemma
3. Use $\sigma$-finiteness for the general case.

If the space is not $\sigma$-finite I think the result is not true, but I don't have a counterexample off the top of my head. :)

**Def($\pi$-system):** We say $\mathcal C \subseteq \mathcal P(X)$ is a $\pi$-system if $\mathcal C$ is closed under finite intersections.

**Def($\Lambda$-system):** We say $\Lambda \subseteq \mathcal P(X)$ is a \textit{$\lambda$-system} if

1. $X \in \Lambda$;
2. if $A_i \in \Lambda$ with $A_i \subseteq A_{i+1}$ for $i \in \mathbb{N}$, then $\bigcup_{i = 1}^\infty A_i \in \Lambda$;
3. if $A,B \in \Lambda$ with $A \subseteq B$, then $B - A \subseteq \Lambda$.

**Dynkin's Lemma:** If $\mathcal C$ is a $\pi$-system and $\Lambda \supseteq \mathcal C$ is a $\lambda$-system, then $\Lambda \supseteq \sigma(\mathcal C)$.

Comment: I forgot to add conditions. Thank you.

Comment: I use text book "Probability" written by Davar Khoshnevisan. I did not find Dynkin's lemma in my book.

Comment: Then maybe you can try other sources. I am going to edit with the statement of the lemma, but don't ask me for the proof ;)